# Dynamically change a value on a asp.net page without actually refreshing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I have a label, let's call it LblA.  I have a SqlDataSource, let's call it sds.  Now, I have selected out and managed to get specific values using the select function.  I want to set LblA's text to the value selected out of sds.  I need this to occur every 5 (or as many as I specify really) seconds.  I orignally used a timer object, however, for any of you who have used the timer object before, it likes to refresh the page, this makes it very hard to navigate off of the page; not only that, it's sloppy.  Does anybody know a way to **easilly** update LblA's text from sds without refreshing the actual page.

I've read around and came to the conclusion that I need to use ajax, err... jQuery.  However, I really don't know anything about the two except that they are both Javascript libraries?  I need a simple way, you might even have to explain it to me like I'm an idiot.

I'm using VB.net and ASP.net just so you know.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Try this as a jQuery ajax starting point http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Rate_me:_Using_Ajax

Comment: You probably should hit the books a bit and learn what ajax actually is to tackle this one. jQuery is indeed a javascript library, but ajax is not a library. It describes a set of technologies that make asynchronous calls possible from a web client. The name was derived from the technologies - (A)synchronous (J)avascript (A)nd (X)ml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it simple use [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx) If you want more control and efficiency, use [jQuery's Content](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

Comment: I'd say UpdatePanel since the OP doesn't really understand ajax. It's going to offer the easiest path to implementing ajax functionality.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds great!  I'll start using it right away :)